# How do I access IPV6 from IPV4?

Tags: ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

I have been searching for a long time ipv4 to ipv6 proxy program but i nothing found... Currently i have IPv4 address however i would like to try IPv6 address. Is there a simple solution for IPV6 access from an IPV4 network?

I am running Windows XP and connected to the internet over a WIFI connection

I've tried TunnelBroker.net (I did not understand what to do), convert ipv4 to ipv6 software (joking?), gogoCLIENT - Basic Version and gogoCLIENT - Home Access Version none of which is working for me.

If possible I'd like a simple solution - I'm not an engineer and would prefer something not too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's IPV6 tunnels and proxies. You're talking about a tunnel in this case I believe.

If you want to access IPv6 resources as a client, I believe installing [Teredo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) should do the trick, somewhat slowly - `netsh interface ipv6 install` installs IPV6 support and `netsh interface ipv6 set teredo client` installs teredo

Setting up IPV6 tunnels is a pain unless its a single computer connected directly to the net, *or* your router can connect to a tunnel broker.

The only options thats worked on my specific setup is the gogo6 client with the udpv6 option, and its worked perfectly behind a lan with no other configuration for me. Gogo went defunct and their webpage has a domain squatter so it won't work any more.

As for tunnel broker - I notice you've tried this but without knowing the specific errors and messages its hard to say what is going on.

If its 'simply' to access ipv6 websites there might be 6 to 4 proxies - [sixxs had a web proxy available](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/), but they [shut down services in 2017](https://www.sixxs.net/sunset/)

Comment: Must be a comment to a previous answer, but well. Another proxy in case you're looking for something simple: http://www.ipv6proxy.net